# How to disable pagination on a gallery template?

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

With the pagination activated in the Options panel and when using different gallery templates, is there a way to disable pagination on a specified template?
If I have more than one gallery on a page, and have pagination turned on for the thumbnails, then the pagination on one gallery also controls the pagination on the other galleries on the page

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could probably use something like :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id=2 0-1000]'); ?>
```

which would show them all... you could replace the second number (in this case 1000) with a variable that would fetch a number of pictures in a gallery..

Comment: Thats a really good idea, but i dont have custom templates, so the id=2 is not fixed

Comment: how do you call the gallery? id is the id of the gallery, not the id of the template..